# class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition of content type: multipart/form-data;

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to upload a file using REST API (I'm using wildfly Server), and I'm getting this error:

> failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition of content type: multipart/form-data;

This my code:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);

        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(com.services.DocumentFacadeREST.class);
    }

}

@Stateless
@Path("documents")
public class DocumentFacadeREST{

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        String uploadedFileLocation = "E://uploadFileRest/"+ fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return output;

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the dependencies that I use in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hornetq</groupId>
       <artifactId>hornetq-core</artifactId>
       <version>snap-r9548</version>
 </dependency>
```

My html form:

```
   <form action="webresources/documents/upload2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <p>
          Select a file : 
          <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
   </form>
```

Please can you help me to know why I got the error, I spent all the day in investigation without any result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried this on Glassfish instead of Wildfly just to see?

Comment: hello @KG6ZVP , thank you so much for you attention, the problem was in the implementation OF REST API, Wildfly uses restEasy and not jersey.

Comment: So you aren't trying to add a Jersey servlet to an app running on Wildfly?

Comment: no idon't know how to use Jersy implementation on Wildfly, do you have any idea/example on how to uses it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use Jersey on Wildfly?

Comment: because it supports @FormDataParam InputStream uploadedInputStream,@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition  that allows me to do what i want with uploaded file, for example getting the name,size... of file , and this is difficult if you i use restEasy , you can check this link if you want more details about this issue http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115153/discussion-between-kg6zvp-and-ali).

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: yes it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use resteasyaxrs instead of jersy in wildfly

jars needed

1. List item
2. resteasyjaxrs.jar
3. resteasy-multipart-provider.jar
4. commonsi0.jar

**Rest Api**

```
@Path("/uploadfile")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(MultipartFormDataInput input) {
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> uploadForm = input.getFormDataMap();
    List<InputPart> inputParts = uploadForm.get("file");
}
```

Comment: please go through the comments on the question and try to add a usable example for user to understand better